# The game sound and ringtone ring at the same time

Tags: android, audio

I have a question for **AudioFocus**

Incoming a call during play game.

The game sound and ringtone ring at the same time!

In general,Only one sound can be showed if we request the AudioFocus before play sound,However the game sound and ringtone ring at the same time.

- Incoming call request AudioFocus in [CallAudioManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telecomm/+/android-6.0.1_r16/src/com/android/server/telecom/CallAudioManager.java#122)
- try to request AudioFocus before Ringtone play --> failed(AudioManager.requestAudioFocus return 0)

## Question:

- How can we analysis this issue?
- is there any way to LOCK the audiofocus?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

Comment: By default, the audio manager will stop any playing source when have incomming call to play ringtone

Comment: @Karakuri **Incoming call request AudioFocus in CallAudioManager.java** and return success!

Comment: I/MediaFocusControl( 1956):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from AudioFocus_For_Phone_Ring_And_Calls req=2flags=0x4
D/AudioService( 1956): to MediaFocusControl.requestAudioFocus,**clientId=AudioFocus_For_Phone_Ring_And_Calls,callingPackageName=com.android.server.telecom,ret=1**
 java.lang.Exception
at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.requestAudioFocus(AudioService.java:5391)
 at android.media.AudioManager.requestAudioFocusForCall(AudioManager.java:2471)
 at com.android.server.telecom.CallAudioManager$1.handleMessage(CallAudioManager.java:122)